# Increase a number in an function and reload the function

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have this piece of code,

```
let spin = new TimelineMax();

spin.to($('.particle'), 150, {
    rotation: 360,
    repeat: -1,
    transformOrigin: '50% 50%',
    ease: Linear.easeNone
});
```

What I need to do is to change the **150** every second (interval) which indicate how fast the spin is going and this to appear real-time. What's the best method to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to `clear` the current `TimelineMax` and start another one:

```
let spin = new TimelineMax();

setInterval(() => {
    spin.clear();
    spin.to($('.particle'), Math.random(), {
        rotation: 360,
        repeat: -1,
        transformOrigin: '50% 50%',
        ease: Linear.easeNone
    });
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like [Generators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators) for this,

```js
function* myGen() {
  let spin = 0;
  for (;;) {
    yield spin += 150;
  }
}

const gen = myGen();
const start = setInterval(() => {
  var next = gen.next();
  if (next.done) {
    clearInterval(start);
  } else {
    // your code here, commenting it for now
    
    // spin.to($('.particle'), next.value, {
    // rotation: 360,
    // repeat: -1,
    // transformOrigin: '50% 50%',
    // ease: Linear.easeNone
    // });
    
    console.log(next.value);
  }
}, 1000)
```

For long-running scripts, you might want to consider a [worker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers)